# How to trigger Bonjour / mDNS / ZeroConf messages using Indy

Tags: delphi, indy

I need to discover an mDNS device on Windows and macOS using Indy and Delphi/FreePascal. See http://www.multicastdns.org/.

I've successfully listened to the messages using an TIdIPMCastClient, if I use an external tool called ZeroConfBrowser, to trigger these.

So how can I trigger these messages myself? Preferably with a filtering of only the "product"._tcp.local devices, I'm interested in.

Note that using external code, like Apples Bonjour DLL, is not an option for deployment reasons.

FWIW the device itself uses the lwIP framework for mDNS support.

Here's the snippets I've used so far:

```
  object IdIPMCastClient1: TIdIPMCastClient
    Bindings = <
      item
        IP = '0.0.0.0'
        Port = 5353
      end>
    DefaultPort = 5353
    MulticastGroup = '224.0.0.251'
    ReuseSocket = rsTrue
    ThreadedEvent = True
    OnIPMCastRead = IdIPMCastClient1IPMCastRead
    Left = 484
    Top = 48
  end
  object IdDNSResolver1: TIdDNSResolver
    QueryType = [qtPTR]
    WaitingTime = 5000
    AllowRecursiveQueries = True
    Host = '224.0.0.251'
    Port = 5353
    IPVersion = Id_IPv4
    Left = 456
    Top = 136
  end

procedure TfrmETMain.btnmDNSSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdIPMCastClient1.Active:= not IdIPMCastClient1.Active;
end;

procedure TfrmETMain.btnResolveHostClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdDNSResolver1.QueryType:= [qtPTR];
  IdDNSResolver1.WaitingTime:= 500;
  IdDNSResolver1.Resolve(cbResolveHost.Text);
end;
```

As mentioned in the comments, using TIdDNSResolver did *not* trigger the device to send the message.

Comment: So, you have part of the protocols working - reading responses. What is stopping you from sending requests? What have you tried so far that is not working for you?

Comment: One thing I've tried is using TidDNSResolver to build a qtPTR query and sending it to 224.0.0.251:5353. I can actually see that query with the IPMCastClient, but it does not trigger the response from the device.

Comment: Are you sure the device in question is actually joined to the multicast group `224.0.0.251`? Have you tried sniffing the network traffic to make sure the DNS packets being sent by `TIdDNSResolver` are actually reaching the device, and that any replies it may be sending back are not getting lost on their way back to `TIdDNSResolver`?

Comment: Also, make sure that when `TIdDNSResolver` sends its queries that it is not binding to source port 5353 so that it will be treated as a "legacy" querier so the mDNS server will act like a normal unicast DNS server.  If the mDNS server sees a query come from source port 5353, it will assume the querier is a fully compliant mDNS querier and will act accordingly, which will not work with `TIdDNSResolver`.

Comment: I *presume* the device is part of the multicast group, because I received it's message with the IPMCastClient when triggered with the external tool. And no, I've not managed to sniff and analyze the network traffic as I wouldn't know how to analyze it. For idDNSResolver, which port would you recommend to use?

Comment: And even if IdDNSResolver doesn't know how to interpret the result, shouldn't I see any response with IdIPMCastClient just like I see the query itself?

Comment: any available source port can be used as long as it is not 5353. Looks like `TIdDNSResolver` does not allow you to set a source port at all, though. Might have to tweak its code to expose that. And no, `TIdIPMCastClient` would not see the responses in this case, because `TIdDNSResolver` would be treated as a "legacy" DNS querier (as it is) so the mDNS server would send unicast responses directly to `TIdDNSResolver` only, not multicast responses to the group. Multicast responses are sent to the group only when queries are made by compliant mDNS queriers.

Comment: I might be missing something, but using a different port for `TIdDNSREsolver` worked out of the box using the Port property. I tried port 1234 and it seems this was actually used - as I didn't see the actualy query with the `TIdIPMCastClient` anymore. It didn't trigger any reply unfortunately, i.e. the call to `Resolve` timed out. Or is source port something completely different?

Comment: The `Port` property specifies the destination server port that `TIdDNSResolver` sends to, not the source port that it sends from. Two different things. Looks like `TIdDNSResolver` users a random ephimeral port for its source port, which is mostly good for you, but you do run into the possibility that once in a blue moon it *may* use port 5353, depending on how the OS implements ephimeral ports.